# Copying new files from newly created folders in my S3 bucket to my local machine using PowerShell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3

We have a program running on a server that copies .xml files to our S3 bucket. But it creates folders according to the date.  So a folder for the year is created and then a sub-folder for the month is created, and then yet another sub-folder for the day. For example:

`S3://AppMyBucket/Documents/2018/Oct/05`

So every day it's creating a folder in accordance with the day, `01`, `02`, `03`, etc., and putting .xml files in those folders. I have to create a PowerShell script to run every 15 minutes to copy new files that go into the latest folder created from our S3 bucket to a folder on my local machine and then call another program to process those files.

My question is how can I copy new files created from new folders created in our S3 bucket (`S3://AppBucket/Documents/2018/Oct/05...`) to my local Windows machine (`D:\DocFolder\`) and then call program (AIMParser.exe) to process those .xml files?

Please forgive me as I am a beginner at PowerShell.

Comment: Do you want to download files from today's folder? Or do you need to identify the latest folder? I.e. is it possible that the latest folder is not the todays' folder, when your script is running?

Comment: Also, you have three questions here, so you should really post them separately. 1) Identify the latest folder, 2) Download new files from S3 folder. 3) Call program.

Comment: Thank you so much Reza for responding!  The application that is running will create the folder according to the day so yes the folder that is created today will always be the latest folder. So I need to figure out how to scan S3 for the files put in the latest folder.  In this case that folder will be the day of the month.  Once a new month is created, it will need to detect that a new month and day folder is created as well. The code will need to scan the latest month and then the latest day and the copy the latest files that get dropped in there by the application to my local machine.

Comment: What about the local side? Do you preserve directory structure in `D:\DocFolder`, like `D:\DocFolder\2018\Oct\05`? Or do the files go directly to `D:\DocFolder`? - And how do you identify the new files? Do you keep all files locally, so you want to download only the files that are not present locally yet?

Comment: The code needs to identify the new .xml files that arrive in our S3 bucket (s3://AppBucket/Documents/2018/Oct/08) so it needs to consider that Year/Month/Day directory structure under the s3 bucket s3://AppBucket/Documents/ will change according to today's date. The .xml files needs to be copied directly to D:\DocFolder on my local machine.  Once the .xml Files are copied to my local machine D:\DocFolder, another application will process them and put them somewhere else so there won't be any .xml files in D:\DocFolder once they are process by this application.

Comment: And can the script look to “somewhere else” to see what files were already downloaded? - You should really try harder to precise your requirements.

Comment: I'm sorry Martin I am very new to powershell.  The code does not need to look anywhere else to see what was already downloaded.  The files need to be downloaded to my local machine on D:\DocFolder from S3.  It needs to look in s3://AppBucket/Documents/ under this Documents directory in S3 there are folders and subdirectories that get created according to the date. A folder for the "Year", and then a subdirectory, for the "Month", and then another subdirectory for the "Day". So the Directory structure looks like this s3://AppBucket/Documents/2018/Oct/08/ .

Comment: Under the subdirectory "/08" There will be .xml files.  The code needs to not only get the latest folder created but also get the latest .xml file from the /08 directory (The Day Directory) and copy it to my local machine under D:\DocFolder.  Nothing else. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: So just one latest file, right? But what if that file was already downloaded before?

Comment: Also, what is "latest file"? Does it have some name pattern? Or should the decision be based on file timestamp?

Comment: The Application that is running in the server always creates new .xml files so it would need to copy the latest file based on Timestamp. For the time, you can base it off of Minutes for example (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-1) so that you copy files that are older than 1 minute from the previous file.   The name of the file doesn't matter so you can use *.xml.

Answer (score 0):

The following example:

- Uses [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell) to access the S3 bucket
- Finds the latest year (lexicographically)
- Finds the latest month in the year
- Finds the latest day in the month (lexicographically)
- Finds the latest file in the day (by file timestamp)

```
Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"

$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::S3
    HostName = "s3.amazonaws.com"
    PortNumber = 443
    UserName = "access key id"
    Password = "secret access key"
}

Write-Host "Connecting..."
$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
$session.SessionLogPath = "s3.log"
$session.Open($sessionOptions)

$remotePath = "/AppMyBucket/Documents";
$localPath = "D:\DocFolder"

$yearFolder =
    $session.ListDirectory($remotePath).Files |
        Where-Object { $_.IsDirectory } |
        Sort-Object -Descending |
        Select-Object -First 1
Write-Host "Latest year is $($yearFolder.Name)"

$yearPath = [WinSCP.RemotePath]::Combine($remotePath, $yearFolder.Name)

$monthFolder =
    $session.ListDirectory($yearPath).Files |
        Where-Object { $_.IsDirectory } |
        Sort-Object -Descending -Property @{ Expression = {
            Get-Date -Date "$($_.Name) 1 $($yearFolder.Name)" -Format "MM" } } |
        Select-Object -First 1

Write-Host "Latest month is $($monthFolder.Name)"

$monthPath = [WinSCP.RemotePath]::Combine($yearPath, $monthFolder.Name)

$dayFolder =
    $session.ListDirectory($monthPath).Files |
        Where-Object { $_.IsDirectory } |
        Sort-Object -Descending |
        Select-Object -First 1

Write-Host "Latest day is $($dayFolder.Name)"

$dayPath = [WinSCP.RemotePath]::Combine($monthPath, $dayFolder.Name)

$latest = 
    $session.ListDirectory($dayPath).Files |
        Where-Object { -Not $_.IsDirectory } |
        Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
        Select-Object -First 1

Write-Host "Latest file is $($latest.Name), downloading..."

$session.GetFiles($latest.FullName, (Join-Path $localPath "*")).Check()

Write-Host "Done"
$session.Dispose()
```

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: Hey Martin. Thank you so much!!! I made some changes and ran the script. I replaced the $remotePath = "adpro-chc-prod-rcm/Documents/UAT/" But this is the output: Latest year is tracking-failure.    ....and Latest month is 2018
Latest day is Oct
Latest file is , downloading...

Comment: It looks like the correct `$remotePath` should be something like `/adpro-chc-prod-rcm/Documents/UAT/something` - There seems to be `tracking-failure` and similar subfolders in `UAT`, not year folders.